# Is there a way to ignore the first step of a 2-step test case in SoapUI, using Java?

Tags: java, soapui

I have a 2-step test case. Step 1 retrieves an authentication token. Step 2 applies the token as a header parameter and retrieves (and validates) the response.
Now, for some lower environments, Step 1 is not implemented. In fact, executing it in the lower environment results in a bad request.

My question is: Based on certain conditions, is it possible to not execute Step 1 of the test case, and directly execute Step 2?

I am seeking to execute using SoapUI's Java API.
Something like,

```
testCase.getTestStepAt(0).... (ignore)
```

Comment: How about conditional go to?

Comment: Thanks. How would I implement that using Java API?

Comment: Do you have any code which is not working?